# How do I add text to specific div element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a problem with jquery. My HTML is

```
<div id="first">
   <span class="test"></span>
</div>
<div id="second">
   <span class="test"></span>
<div>
```

Now I am trying to add text in span using Jquery.

```
$j('span.test').text('Welcome');
```

After that it becomes,

```
<div id="first">
    <span class="test">Welcome</span>
</div>
<div id="second">
    <span class="test">Welcome</span>
<div>
```

But, I am tryting to achieve is,

```
<div id="first">
    <span class="test">Welcome</span>
</div>
<div id="second">
    <span class="test"></span>
<div>
```

How can I do that in jquery?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik As he says his code works, I assume he has created a new jQuery alias using `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Several possible alternatives

Others have provided their answers already but let me give you some more alternatives.

```
$("span.test:first").text("Welcome");
$("#first span.test").text("Welcome");
$("span.test").first().text("Welcome");
$("span.test").eq(0).text("Welcome");
$("span.test", "#first").text("Welcome");
```

The second and last one likely being the fastest because they target particular container by ID.
<sup>(internal jQuery optimisations may prove me wrong with any future version)</sup>

### Performance comparison

Here's a [JSPerf test](http://jsperf.com/first-element-matching) that performance compares upper possibilities. As anticipated, the second and last approaches are the fastest of all because element selection is much simplified. I've tried running them on Chrome and you may run them in other browsers if you want to and see differences.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#first span.test').text('Welcome');
```

jQuery selectors are CSS selectors extended with a bit of magic.  You can find everything you need to know here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `:first` selector to say that you only want to add text to the first element the selector finds. Try this:

```
$j('span.test:first').text('Welcome');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/xDPKP/)

Alternatively, you can use the `id` of the parent div to make the selector unique:

```
$j('#first .test').text('Welcome');
```

Comment: I didn't donwnvote but `:first` selector filter matches all elements that are first childs of their parents, which means that all of the `test` divs would still match... So your first solution is of course invalid. It would be ok if you'd do `$("span.test").first()...`

Comment: @RobertKoritnik you're cofusing `:first`, with `:first-child`. `:first` selects the first element of the matching set.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: You're right... My bad... But as mentioned I didn't donwvote so I can't remove it.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik Don't worry, not a problem :)

Comment: You don't need a fiddle for something so simple.  The reason I downvoted is that this is not an adequate use of `:first`.  That's a dangerous selector because it assumes too much about the structure of your document.  A good rule is to not use it across hierarchies.  So using it here would be ok: `<div><span class="test"></span><span class="test"></span></div>`.  The reason is that it's easier to remember to look for a `.test:first` selector if you add a new span to that example, but almost impossible if you cross hierarchies like the OP.

Comment: Ok removing downvote since I posted an answer but you should really consider what I'm saying about `:first`

Comment: Fair point, which is why I included an alternative which didn't use it

Comment: Hm, I wouldn't be such a stickler if it didn't seem like the OP was very new at jQuery.  I'm imagining all kinds of scary code being written :)

Comment: @Milimetric did you seriously just edit my answer to remove a line break which wasn't visible anyway? You could have at least fixed my typo on `selector` ;)

Comment: Check interesting performance tests provided in my answer... It may surprise you. `:first` is the slowest possible way of doing this.

Comment: :) @RoryMcCrossan, no, I actually had to edit in order to remove the downvote.  It was locked in otherwise.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik, that's not surprising at all.  It's yet another reason I don't like the `:first` selector.

Answer (score 0):

In this example you can do what RoRyMcCrossan
For general selection i recommend you to look at this :http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Or you can use this

http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an id, which usually is unique on one page, it woud be best to use the following:

```
$("#first span.test").text("Welcome");
```