# Updating webpage with real-time database value using AJAX+PHP response

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, comet

I’m creating a Javascript game and I’m currently trying to write some code that will show the player’s “Gold Balance” in real time on a html webpage.

The Gold amount is contained in my SQL database, so I’m using `setInterval` with a Javascript function that contains an AJAX call which calls a PHP script that grabs the current balance amount for the player and sends it back as “response”.

I’m able to have this amount appear as a Javascript alert, however I need to have the response appear as text on the webpage inside a `<div>` instead.

This is my current code:

```
<script>
setInterval("checkGold()",5000); 

function checkGold()
{
        $.ajax({
     url: 'scripts/checkGold.php',
    data: "",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
                        alert(response);       
    }});
};
</script>
```

I have this in my html source code, I would like to place the function in a separate file and call it from there, but when I tried this I wasn't able to send the response back to the html page correctly.

I was wondering if anyone knows how to have this response appear as text on the page inside `<div> </div>`?

Also, I was wondering if this method will really update the div in real time (ie, will it auto-refresh the div part of the webpage, showing an up to date value (every 5000 milliseconds)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to look at how to insert text using jQuery selectors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278630/how-i-do-add-text-to-specific-div-element-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, you can use [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-text) to alter the contents of an existing div (which id is "yourDiv"):

```
setInterval("checkGold()",5000); 

function checkGold()
{
    $.ajax({
      url: 'scripts/checkGold.php',
      data: "",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response){
        $('div#yourDiv').text(response);       
      }
    });
};
```

Comment: Hi @iran-rodrigues thanks for your reply, I'm trying your method but I think I'm making a mistake, I'm using your code, and have set the div to: ``<div id="yourDiv"></div>`` however it's not working for me, I think I'm doing something very basic wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have two questions here, so I will try to address both

1) How to append to the DOM using jQuery, instead of an alert:

- in the success callback function, instead of alerting the response, you can simply call

  ```
  $('body').append("<div>"+response+"</div>")
  ```

2) "Real time" Gold Balance

- You should use websockets. Racthet is a good websocket PHP library to help you with this: http://socketo.me/

Comment: Hi @user3191753 thanks for your reply. I'm trying your code in the success callback function but I don't think I'm doing it right. Do I need to write something in the ``<div> </div>`` tags in the html to make this method work?     Also, the response from the database will be different for every player (the PHP passed contains a unique player ID), so would websockets still work for this? Or is the AJAX way a better method? I might have misunderstood the websockets link but is that only for updating multiple users with the same data value? (for example, a blog post)